# Extend an image with transparent portion

Tags: c#, image, alpha-transparency

I am making and photo editor and displaying an image in pictureBox and I resize the image to fit in the pictureBox without effecting its ratio of sides.

Example if the pictureBox is of size (400x400) and the image is of (800x600) i will resize it to (400x300) programatically.

The problem is I want this image to be the size of (400x400) to cover complete pictureBox for this I want to add transparent part in my image to make it from (400x300) to (400x400)

Snapshot of my image on the pictureBox
[image]

In the image above my blue is my image and other part is remaining picturebox.

Again I want image'size (blue one) to be equal to picturebox's size and the remaining part of picturebox is covered by transparent part of picture

Note: I don't want to stretch my image but add transparent part

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way is to create the larger bitmap and then `DrawImage` the picture into it.

```
Bitmap original = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(someFileName);
Size sz = yourPictureBox.ClientSize;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height); 
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    G.DrawImage(original, 0, 0);
yourPictureBox.Image = bmp;
```